# use results from ember data findQuery as ArrayController contentBinding

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to write my first "real" ember app. I've gone through a couple tutorials and I'm now attempting to use ember in conjunction with Ember Data to fetch data from a Rails app and display it.

I've gotten it to fetch the data, parse it, and display it, although I'm not convinced it's in the best way possible. I have an `App.itemsController` that is similar to this:

```
App.itemsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
  content: App.store.findQuery(App.Item, {visible: true}),
});
```

I also have an `App.ItemIndexView`, whose template looks like

```
{{#each App.itemsController}}
    {{id}}{{view App.ItemView item=this}}
{{/each}}
```

I have a couple of questions about this.

First and foremost, I want to allow a user to change an items visibility to false. I have this code in the `App.ItemView` file:

```
acknowledge: function() {
  this.item.set('visible', false);
  App.store.commit();
}
```

the record gets updated, however I want that entire item to drop from the view and it doesn't.  How do I make this record be removed from `App.itemsController.content`?

My second question, which may in fact also answer the first, am I completely off in the boondocks as far as my implementation of this? I feel like there should be a way for me to set something like `contentBinding: 'App.store.findQuery(App.Item, {visible: true})'` and have non-visible ones be removed but I've tried that and nothing shows up. So I'm wondering if something in the way I have my whole app setup is flawed and keeping things from playing nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function instead of `findQuery`:

```
content: App.store.filter(App.Item, function (item) {
  return item.get('visible');
})
```

The result will be re-evaluated when underlying data change. You still have to get data from the server via find/findAll/findQuery though.